# Auto-select highest voted bounty answer has stopped?

Tags: support, reputation, answers, bounties

has it stopped?
I have set a bounty on a question at on SO. only 3 days remain. and today i find some one up-voted an answer that was answered before the bounty was set. if some one is just trying to up vote an answer to get it the bounty that defeats the purpose.
I don't mind losing the bounty for advertising . But i don't want it awarded to some one who has not provided the answer. and if i had the reputation i would have down voted it...

Edit:
what is the prevent some one for just messing around and upvoting any ridiculous answer in any bounty just to see that some one get the reward.

Comment: Isn't 2 up vote is minimum requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't award the bounty amount to a particular answer then the system will automatically award half the bounty amount to the highest voted answer with a score of or +2 or more that was posted *after* the bounty was started.

It doesn't matter if the answer posted before the bounty was started has 10 upvotes - it won't automatically receive half the bounty.

There is nothing to stop people voting up any answer to receive the bounty but the answer must be given after the bounty had started.

If no answer satisfies the auto award bounty rules then the bounty amount will simply disappear.

**EDIT**

If a new answer is posted and has the sufficient amount of votes to receive the auto awarded bounty and you don't want the answer to receive the bounty then the only way to avoid this is to post an answer yourself and award the bounty to your own answer.  You won't actually receive the bounty amount but it will prevent any other answer from receiving it.

Once you amassed enough reputation again you can start another bounty on the same question if you wish.

Comment: if some one posted an incorrect/irrelevant answer and it still got upvoted to more than+2 how do i prevent that answer from being awarded the bounty? i dont want to post some answer and accept it as had read in a highly voted forum post that thats one way to  stop it.I want to leave it open for the future and start a bounty again when i make sufficient reputation .

Comment: @Aditya - I have updated my answer

Comment: good to know i can open up the answer to try next time.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a bounty does not interfere or prevent voting against any existing answers. It does not preclude existing answers from being reworked/edited to get more votes. It does not prevent you from awarding the bounty to any existing answer.

It's all about choice.

- What is true, however, is that if you have set a bounty AND
- there is a new answer AND
- the new answer has at least 2 upvotes AND
- the new answer is the highest voted among the new answers

then.. it will received half the amount you set. This will not include the +50 bonus that the bounty recipient would get were you to award it yourself.