# Is it fair to wait for the bounty to expire and then select the highest voted answer?

Tags: discussion, ethics, bounties

Recently I have answered a bounty question [I'm looking for a way to add my own file template to Eclipse. How to do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615555/im-looking-for-a-way-to-add-my-own-file-template-to-eclipse-how-to-do-it), to my surprise the person who asked the question waited till the bounty got expired and the very next day he accepted my answer with 5 upvotes.

I know ***life is not fair***, ***sh## happens*** and all **:)**. Though that was kind of rude and cheating.

Anyway life goes on. But the question remains: Is it fair? Shouldn't there be some mechanism of detecting this?

**Note:** This question is not related with these questions:

1. [Unawarded bounty goes to highest voted answer if accepted answer is from before the bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54796/unawarded-bounty-goes-to-highest-voted-answer-if-accepted-answer-is-from-before-t)
2. [Auto-select highest voted bounty answer has stopped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82841/auto-select-highest-voted-bounty-answer-has-stopped)

Comment: The asker probably simply forgot to award the bounty. Happens to me all the time. They lost the reputation anyway, so they have gained nothing

Comment: It happened to me once where I posted some bounty and was unable to accept the correct answer (unable to access computer). I posted a comment apologising which I think good behaviour. It also serves as a flag for others that it wasn't just auto-accepted but really did answer the problem I had.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not cheating. Even though you only got half the bounty, the question asker "lost" 50 reputation anyhow. There's no reputation benefit in not awarding the bounty.

As for fair: yours might still be the best answer, but the question asker might have hoped for more. Or, the question asker somehow forgot to award it in time, was just too late (that's a nasty side effect of trying to wait as long as possible), or didn't understand the system.

Comment: I think i can take your words :). Accepting your answer.